# Symfony Login error - Invalid credentials

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, doctrine

I have a form that i want to log a user in - i have loaded fixtures into the database but when i have tried following tutorials i keep getting bad credentials or invalid credentials i will include all my relevant files, if anyone can point anything out that i'm missing id be forever in your debt!

```
 <?php

 namespace AppBundle\Forms;

 use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
 use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

class LoginType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'username',
                TextType::class, [
                    'constraints' => [
                        new NotBlank()
                    ]
                ]
            )
            ->add(
                'password',
                PasswordType::class, [
                    'constraints' => [
                        new NotBlank()
                    ]
                ]
            );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
        ]);
    }
}
```

and my controller -

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller\Login;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use AppBundle\Forms\LoginType;
use AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class LoginpageController {
    protected $formFactory;
    protected $templating;
    protected $router;
    protected $authenticationUtils;
    protected $encoder;
    protected $userRepository;

    public function __construct (
        FormFactoryInterface $formFactory,
        EngineInterface $templating,
        RouterInterface $router,
        AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils,
        UserPasswordEncoder $encoder,
        UserRepository $userRepository
    ) {
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->templating = $templating;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->authenticationUtils = $authenticationUtils;
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function __invoke(Request $request) {
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->formFactory->create(LoginType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isValid()) {
            return new RedirectResponse (
                $this->router->generate('home'),
                Response::HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
            );
        }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $this->authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        return new Response(
            $this->templating->render(
                'AppBundle:loginpage:loginpage.html.twig', [
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                    'error'         => $error
                ]
            )
        );
    }
}
```

My Form -

```
 {% if error %}
     <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
 {% endif %}

  <form method="POST" action="{{ path('login') }}">
  {{ form_start(form) }}
  {{ form_row(form.username) }}
  <br>
  {{ form_row(form.password) }}
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
  {{ form_end(form) }}
  </form>
```

My security -

```
security:
    providers:
        user_database:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 11

    firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

        main:
           pattern:   ^/
           anonymous: ~
           provider: user_database
           form_login:
              login_path: /login
              check_path: /login
           logout:
              path:   /logout
              target: /

    access_control:
         - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Repo -

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements  UserLoaderInterface {
    public function save(User $user) {
        $this->_em->persist($user);
        $this->_em->flush();
    }

    public function delete(User $user) {
        $this->_em->remove($user);
        $this->_em->flush();
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username) {
        $user = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.username = :username or u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('username', $username)
            ->setParameter('email', $username)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();

        if (null === $user) {
            $message = print_r(
                'Unable to find an active admin AppBundle:User object identified by "%s".',
                $username
            );
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message);
        }
        return $user;
    }
}
```

ORM mapping -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
<entity repository-class="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository" name="AppBundle\Entity\User" table="user">
<id name="id" type="guid" column="id">
  <generator strategy="UUID"/>
</id>
<field name="firstName" type="string" column="first_name" length="255"/>
<field name="lastName" type="string" column="last_name" length="255"/>
<field name="email" type="string" column="email" length="255" unique="true"/>
<field name="username" type="string" column="username" length="255" unique="true"/>
<field name="password" type="string" column="password" length="4096"/>
<field name="roles" type="string" column="roles" length="255"/>
<field name="createdAt" type="datetime" column="createdAt"/>
<field name="isActive" type="boolean" column="isActive"/>
</entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Comment: While creating record using Fixtures did you applied same algorithm on password field value as mentioned in `security.yml` file and that is encoder: `bcrypt`.

Comment: Yes, i've never changed the value since i first implemented it, i checked on this, the value can be changed and the encoded password of previous values will always remember the cost and remain the same even if the encoder cost is changed down the line

Answer (score 1):

I got bitten by this error message as well.

My cause was having duplicate usernames in my users table (and thus not one but many multiple users got returned when selecting on username). I have no idea why I have forgotten this...

So make sure your username column/field have a unique index. Pretty obvious, but I hope it saves someones time.

On top of your entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @UniqueEntity("username")
 */
```

And in the body of your entity class :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(unique=true, type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $username;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem!

IN my Fixture data, i was calling another variable to encode as my password here is the diffrence here

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    foreach ($this->users as $user) {
        $userAdmin = new User();

        $userAdmin->setName($user['name']);
        $userAdmin->setEmail($user['email']);

        $userAdmin->setPassword($user['password']);

        $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
        $password = $encoder->encodePassword($userAdmin, 'secret.password');
        $userAdmin->setPassword($password);

        $userAdmin->setRoles($user['roles']);
        $userAdmin->setUsername($user['username']);
        $userAdmin->setIsActive($user['isActive']);
        $userAdmin->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));

        $manager->persist($userAdmin);
    }
    $manager->
```

## Fix:

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    foreach ($this->users as $user) {
        $userAdmin = new User();

        $userAdmin->setName($user['name']);
        $userAdmin->setEmail($user['email']);

        $userAdmin->setPassword($user['password']);

        $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
        $password = $encoder->encodePassword($userAdmin, $userAdmin->getPassword());
        $userAdmin->setPassword($password);

        $userAdmin->setRoles($user['roles']);
        $userAdmin->setUsername($user['username']);
        $userAdmin->setIsActive($user['isActive']);
        $userAdmin->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));

        $manager->persist($userAdmin);
    }
    $manager->flush();
}
```

Comment: For other people with similar issues reload your fixtures and it should work fine,  also make sure that youre not using two encoders one in security.yml and one in your fixture data id so

Comment: In my case I was overwriting it in an ORM event listener... ‍♂️